# Knowing the range of variable types needed

Tags: data-types

So, if I (as the programmer) know that my value will never exceed a small number (say 100) because it is really just a counter-controlled loop or whatever, may I use `short` or `char` instead of `int` for the minute memory savings?

Comment: Be aware that many variables (and temporary values) in programs never occupy any memory at all, or rather occupy registers which are of fixed size anyway (erasing any size difference by rounding up to the register size).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, and this will likely work. As FrustratedWithFormsDesigner mentioned you will need to be sure of bounds checking.

Another important factor is that as delnan said registers are fixed size. But using them as a smaller type *may* mean using different, less-efficient instructions if the variable's size is not the computer's word size.

Most of the time there is not much to be gained from using variable sizes smaller than the machine's word size. Embedded systems may benefit, and if a file format specifies specific field sizes then of course use those. Another thing to keep in mind is memory alignment, a 16 bit variable may be aligned on a 32 or 64 bit memory boundary with unused space between variables. Or it may not. Or it may be a compiler flag.

**Edit:** the comments brought up a good point. Even with a 64 bit word size, int is still likely 32 bits (C/C++, desktop platforms). The reasons are historical and out of context here. However, a modern 64 bit CPU such as the Intel Core i7 is heavily optimized for 32 *and* 64 bit arithmetic. Any CPU *should* be fast when using ints the same size as its native word size. However, there is a *lot* of 32 bit software out there that these CPUs need to be able to run and run well. Working with ints smaller than 32 bits may or may take a performance hit, as you are now outside the realm of what the CPU is optimized for. In practice I would expect any performance hit to be minimal, and the memory difference would be negligible as well. File this one under "premature optimization."

Comment: Interesting. So since the Linux command `getconf WORD_BIT` returns `32` on mine, does that mean I should just use `int`?

Comment: Depends on the language and platform. C and C++ define ranges for their data types, although in practice on a desktop OS int is 32 bits. Even on a 64 bit OS/CPU that is acceptable, a 32 bit int is still widely used and works well even in 64 bit programs. As I said in my answer, there is not much if any gain from going under 32 bit for integers.

Comment: @floopdagoop it depends on the language, as Snowman said. Most have "int" default to 32 bit as it's the standard, but you can usualyl specific int16/32/64 when defining the variable. Each of these types will block off that much memory, which is "inefficient" for memory purposes, but telling the processor to hack out chunks of memory that are not it's standard size can take a bit of extra time. You just need to measure you need for extra memory with your need for faster performance. It's all about economy of scale at that point.

Comment: @JMD The 32 bit integer is so common that Java I believe makes this a standard size for all `int` and smaller types.  Even declaring a `byte` variable, the JVM will still allocate 32 bits of the heap while only utilizing the first 8 bits.  The reason for this is performance I would imagine.

Comment: @maple_shaft it appears that Java uses 32 bit chunks of memory for stack variables, which explains why small primitives still use 32 bits. Arrays of primitives are different since an array will likely (but not necessarily) be allocated in TLS or the heap.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could. Of course, if you do that you should also include code that validates your variable so that if an input *is* greater than 100, you get a sensible error message. And it's also a good idea to add comments to explain *why* you're using `char` instead of `int` (if that's what you end up doing). It might not be obvious to everyone. Are you working in an environment where memory is so tight that this will make a significant difference to your program? Are you doing this for educational reasons?

Comment: I'm currently just learning as hobby, though I do want to go to college for CS. I'm sure on any modern system, extracting the `3-byte` difference between `char` and `int` is practically meaningless, but I do like the idea of efficiency.

Comment: @floopdagoop: I think the only place that you *might* see a significant difference would be on some sort of embedded system with very limited memory, and an architecture that would best be able to take advantage of this sort of coding.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes** This is especially useful in for loops. People often just use int, or allow var to determine what the variable type should be. This is inefficient (but not terribly so), but for people like me who like to get every ounce of performance and are just tickled pink by using the most perfect datatype for a situation, this is awesome.

```
for(SByte i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
...code
}
```

SByte allows -128 to 127. I love this little datatype because it saves on memory and is the most appropriate datatype for the situation where warranted.

However, integer, in some languages, is the fastest datatype for arithmetic operations, even when it is way to large of a container for what you need.

> Arithmetic operations are faster with integral types than with other
>   data types. They are fastest with the Integer and UInteger types in
>   Visual Basic. [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ae55hdtk(v=vs.100).aspx) (msdn.com)

So in loops, yes, use this. When doing arithmetic, however, air on the side of caution and use an int unless you research the language you are using first to see what the fastest type is.

--Adding another example I gave in the comments--

You have a class that has a 100 ints in it, but none of the ints will ever go above a value of 10. Every time you create an object of that class you are blocking off 32 bits per int creating 32*100=3200 bits. If you replaced those ints with sBytes you are now blocking off 8*100=800. You are saving 2400 bits for use anywhere else.

Comment: I call BS on the loop being faster. At best, it uses the same registers and operations and comes out equally fast; at worst it has to do some sign extensions and winds up ever so slightly slower. Please give evidence of your assertion.

Comment: Never said it was faster. Please read before calling BS and looking like a tool.

Comment: You say you "get tickled pink" by using the "most perfect" datatype for the situation. Since you spoke specifically about loop variables I can't imagine you were talking about memory savings. So please explain what you meant if I misunderstood.

Comment: That I did. Please state your concern with my answer and I'll work through it with you, or even add to my answer and tweak accordingly. The only caveat is that you need to actually have concern with something I said and not something you imagined.

Comment: You edited your comment after I responded, you tricky man. For me, the perfect datatype is fits the use case as closely as possible. If your value will never be out of bounds for a SByte, then an int is overkill.

Comment: His concern isn't imagined. You said so yourself that the basic integer type is generally the fastest. Therefore using any other data type for the iteration variable will be at best the same speed and at worst slower. Plus, like @delnan mentioned in another comment, if the loop variable ends up in a register there's 0 memory savings, and even if it ends up on the stack the savings will be only a handful of bytes and then evaporate when the method returns. It just makes no sense to worry about this. You could make a case for choosing the right data types in structs and arrays.

Comment: @Doval his concern is imagined, since I say right in my answer that int is faster for arithmetic operation IN SOME LANGUAGES. I point that out already. He's not adding anything.

Comment: Okay, let's get down to specifics. I take issue with this part: "People often just use int, or allow var to determine what the variable type should be. This is inefficient (but not terribly so)". And the advise to use a smaller type for loops, for which I see no justification except an aesthetic choice dressed up as relevant experience (" people like me who like to get every ounce of performance").

Comment: Also, the question isn't "what makes the most sense", it's "may I use". I answered that yes, you can, and then threw in an example of one use case and then pointed out a use case where you wouldn't want to use it. What's your issue?

Comment: @delnan I call it out as inefficient because blocking out 32-64 bits for a value that takes up 8 bits is a waste. To say that it's not inefficient is to say that there is literally no purpose for sByte and we should always use int.

Comment: If you carefully noted that there are occasions where shrinking integers by 25% is useful, I'd be fully with you. But that's not what this answer does. It speaks about a quite narrow niche in absolute terms with unjustified vigor.

Comment: @delnan the question itself is asking about a narrow niche. Here's an example: you have an class that has a 100 ints in it, but none of the ints will ever go above a value of 10. Every time you create an object of that class you are blocking off 32 bits per int creating 32*100=3200 bits. If you replaced those ints with sBytes you are now creating 8*100=800. You are saving 2400 bits for use anywhere else. Yes, this is a small savings, but if you have a million of these objects you can see that the savings add up.(Sorry, I accidentally hit enter and then had to edit to get the rest of this in)

Comment: I wasn't talking about the "I only need eight bits at most" niche (which is reasonably common), I was talking about the "you have so many integers that using a smaller type actually makes any appreciable difference" niche, which is far more narrow. How many classes have hundred int members? And how often will you have *millions* of such objects? As an analogy, OP is asking about going out without sun screen and you spend your whole answer talking about the virtues of covering *all* skin with light cloth, because that's what it takes in the Sahara.

Comment: @delnan that analogy is awful. He asked "may I use this" and I said yes. Your comments are not helping me flesh out my answer at all. If you disagree with my answer submit your own, these comments are not meant for arguments. Feel free to give a -1 for my answer. I'll still +1 yours if it makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16259/discussion-between-delnan-and-jmd).

Comment: This is not especially useful in for loops.  Assuming it has an actual effect on the memory used in compiled code, you end up saving *a number of bytes that you can literally count on one hand*.

Comment: @MichaelShaw it's true that the savings are minute, but the question already took that into account.

Comment: @JMD I'm not taking issue with your answer's "Yes", I'm taking issue with your answer's "This is especially useful in for loops".

Comment: @MichaelShaw you need to block off the memory for the int, whether it's for a scoped variable or a class. The memory savings are there either way.

Comment: @JMD The "memory savings" you're referring to wouldn't be more than about 14 bytes for the entire program (assuming that we go from 8 byte to 1 byte data types and we have nested for loops) and probably would be more like 3.  That's assuming that there is any memory allocation at all (as delnan pointed out in his comment on the question, loop counters could be stored in registers), and that there is no padding or alignment restrictions that make the memory savings go away.

Comment: @MichaelShaw correct, the memory savings are minute, which the OP already acknowledged. You aren't adding anything to this.

Comment: @JMD: Your answer is incorrect.  It states that "This is especially useful in for loops" which is wrong.  It may be especially useful in arrays, but its usefulness in for loops is either incredibly tiny or nonexistent, most likely nonexistent.  You may or may not fix your answer, but pointing out that an answer is incorrect (along with why) is actually quite useful.

Comment: @MichaelShaw it's really dependent on the framework, but from what I've seen, when you declare an sByte you partition out less memory. Since this can be dangerous when you don't know how large the number will be, sBytes can be useful in loops when you know exactly how large it can get.